# Hide a class when another class display is set to inline-block !important

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to hide one class based on another class display being set to `inline-block !important` using only JavaScript. Here's what I have so far:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  hidedeliveryFunction() {
    var outOfstock = document.getElementsByClassName(".action,.alert"),
        deliveryOptions = document.getElementsByClassName(".shipping-product-info");

    if (outOfstock.style.display === "inline-block !important") {
      deliveryOptions.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<!-- if this div display is inline-block !important -->
<div class="product alert stock">
  <a href="#" data-post="" title="Out of stock" class="action alert">Out of stock</a>
</div>

<!-- then this div display is none -->
<div class="shipping-product-info">
  <div class="ship-clickcollect option--available">
    <div class="shipping-product-info--options">
      <div class="shipping-product-info--icon"></div>
      <div class="shipping-product-info--available"></div>
      <div class="shipcontroller">
        <p>Available on orders over $40. Collection in 1-7 days. WA orders 1-14 days. <a href="/click-and-collect"
            target="_blank">More&nbsp;info&nbsp;»</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ship-homedelivery option--not-available">
    <div class="shipping-product-info--options">
      <div class="shipping-product-info--icon"></div>
      <div class="shipping-product-info--available"></div>
      <div class="shipcontroller">
        <p>Free express shipping over $99. Some exclusions apply. <a href="/free-shipping-australia-wide">More&nbsp;info&nbsp;»</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you take some time and clean up the formatting of the code so we can all read it a little easier? And, then clarify what class needs to be hidden (and what you mean by hidden in the first place) when the other CSS is present.

Comment: And, are we talking about the first `div` having that CSS set as inline or are you talking about if it has been set to that CSS from some other code?

Comment: why don't you show any css part ?

Comment: Yes, just updated with more clarity. Sorry, if it already has been set to inline from a stylesheet

Comment: what is `hidedeliveryFunction();{`  seem you have keybord malfunction ?

Comment: Didn't realise that was still in there, it was from a prior attempt. I don't typically code javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not need to test for the `!important` part in your use case. [`.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) should take care of it:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // Don't use .getElementsByClassName() as it returns a live node list
  // which isn't right for most use cases. And because you are only looking
  // for a single element match, use .querySelector() instead.
  var outOfstock = document.querySelector(".product.alert.stock");
  var deliveryOptions = document.querySelector(".shipping-product-info");

  if (getComputedStyle(outOfstock).display === "inline-block") {
    deliveryOptions.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
.alert { display:inline-block !important; }
```

```html
<!-- if this div display is inline-block !important -->
<div class="product alert stock">
  <a href="#" data-post="" title="Out of stock" class="action alert">Out of stock</a>
</div>

<!-- then this div display is none -->
<div class="shipping-product-info">
  <div class="ship-clickcollect option--available">
    <div class="shipping-product-info--options">
      <div class="shipping-product-info--icon"></div>
      <div class="shipping-product-info--available"></div>
      <div class="shipcontroller">
        <p>Available on orders over $40. Collection in 1-7 days. WA orders 1-14 days. <a href="/click-and-collect"
            target="_blank">More&nbsp;info&nbsp;»</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ship-homedelivery option--not-available">
    <div class="shipping-product-info--options">
      <div class="shipping-product-info--icon"></div>
      <div class="shipping-product-info--available"></div>
      <div class="shipcontroller">
        <p>Free express shipping over $99. Some exclusions apply. <a href="/free-shipping-australia-wide">More&nbsp;info&nbsp;»</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see this works if it is placed into the "product alert stock" elements itself but the element display is being set from a linked stylesheet not as an inline style, unfortunately.

Comment: @ReeceStevenson That's what I asked you up in the comments, but you didn't reply. Let me modify the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to this platform and thought I had replied. Thanks for helping though.

Comment: Thanks this is working well, sorry for the miscommunication and lack of knowledge. I didn't know that .querySelector work better for a single item, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but you can try to remove "shipping-product-info" class when the "outOfstock" element met the condition

```
deliveryOptions.classList.remove("shipping-product-info")
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can use like this code to hide

```
var hidediv = document.getElementById("hidediv");
var showdiv = document.getElementById("showdiv");
if (hidediv.style.display === "none") {
     showdiv.style.display = "block";
   } else {
     hidediv.style.display = "none";
   }
```

Comment: How will your `if` condition ever catch `inline-block !important` if you aren't testing for it?

Comment: oh sorry, so just add impotant use javascript like this code you mean ? ---> . 
document.getElementsById('divId').style.cssText = "display:none !important";

Comment: There is no such thing as `getElementsById`. And, `cssText` returns the entire rule, along with a selector.